# createStoredProcedureQuery blocks forever

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, derby, hibernate-entitymanager

I have been trying to create backups of a derby database from within a Java EE application running on Glassfish. I am trying to accomplish that using StoredProcedureQueries which work fine in the method below.

```
public Backup doBackup(String path) throws QueryTimeoutException { 
    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery(
            "SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE");
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, java.lang.String.class,
            ParameterMode.IN);
    query.setParameter(1, path);
    query.execute();
}
```

However I also want to create Backups automatically like a cronjob. To do this I thought I'd simply use a ScheduledExecuterService that is being executed every n hours. I've written the following method for this:

```
public void startScheduledBackupRunner() {
    long delay = 1;

    Runnable backupRunner = () -> {
        try {
            doBackup("/foo/bar/");
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            logger.fatal(e);
        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(backupRunner, delay, delay, TimeUnit.HOURS);
}
```

The backupRunner thread is executed successfully and it also calls the doBackup() method. However it seems to get stuck when calling createStoredProcedureQuery(). I injected the EntityManager em like this if it matters:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

Am I missing something important here? Any clues are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a solution that doesn't involve creating a separate thread using the `@Schedule` annotation. It does not fix the underlying problem and I still don't know why the first approach did not work, it is just another and probably much more elegant way of performing scheduled tasks.